# ImageIO.createImageInputStream could not work on java platform se 7

Tags: java, javax.imageio

The code below works fine for previous versions but could not work after upgrading to Java 7.

Can anyone help?

Codes:

```
if (imageFile.exists())

System.out.println(imageFile.getPath()+" :"+ imageFile.getName());
      // prepare to read the input

final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (imageFile);  

ImageInputStreamiis=null;
iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(fis);          
final Iterator<ImageReader> imageReaders = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
ImageReader reader = imageReaders.next();
reader.setInput(iis, true, false);
```

```
Errors:
C:\Users\apps\Documents\DSC_1244.jpg :DSC_1244.jpg
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi: Provider it.tidalwave.imageio.io.FileImageInputStream2Spi not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:231)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:369)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(IIORegistry.java:210)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.(IIORegistry.java:138)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(IIORegistry.java:159)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.(ImageIO.java:65)
    at hk.dawntech.digps2map.PhotoManagerImagePreview.paint(PhotoManagerImagePreview.java:50)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1482)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1413)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Comment: I have no issue using Java 1.7.0_04.  Try using `ImageIO.read(imageFile)` and/or `iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(imageFile);` instead.  If that doesn't work, make sure that the file you're reading is actually valid.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. It seems the problem is when calling serviceloder... any idea on the issue?

Comment: You seem to have a `ImageIO` service plugin which is not supported by the `ImageIO`.  You might like to have a read through [this](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/fabriziogiudici/archive/2008/07/openjdk_is_a_ve.html?force=249)

Comment: Can you upload (e.g. to [imgur](http://imgur.com/)) the exact image that is causing problems?

Comment: Mad, not sure the issue is the same with the blog. actually, the meta-inf/services could not create, so there has no any external plugin serivce, right?

Comment: Hi andrew, the jpg file is fine to load on jdk1.6, so i guess it's not related to the format of the file..

Answer (score 1):

I answered a question that is basically the same issue here: [ImageIO methods not working after switching to Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19131782/1428606).

The only difference is that this exception is caused by an `ImageInputStreamSpi` being attempted registered as an `ImageReaderSpi`.