# ImageIO methods not working after switching to Java 7

Tags: java-7, javax.imageio

The program works fine when I was using Java 6, but the error occurs after switching to Java 7. 
Same image files have been used to test, so it might not be the problem with the image format.

Part of the code: (Error occur on the line ImageIO.write)

```
try {
        ImageIO.write(bimage, format, bstream);
        bstream.close();
        return bstream.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Error:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi: Provider com.slb.imageio.plugins.wsq.writer.WSQImageWriterSpi not a subtype
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:231)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:181)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:369)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry$1.run(IIORegistry.java:241)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerInstalledProviders(IIORegistry.java:249)
at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerStandardSpis(IIORegistry.java:184)
at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(IIORegistry.java:137)
at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(IIORegistry.java:159)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(ImageIO.java:65)
```

Not only ImageIO.write(), but other ImageIO methods are not working as well
such as:

```
JPEGImageWriter imageWriter = (JPEGImageWriter)ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jpeg").next();
        ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(out);
```

I have tried searching for similar errors but no solution was found.
Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Does the library work with Java7?

Comment: What is "com.slb.imageio.plugins"? A library you installed? If so, try to contact the vendor.

Comment: @Thilo Yes, it is a library. So the problem is caused by it? 
I also have the source codes of the library with me but it doesn't show any errors upon compilation

Answer (score 2):

The exception is caused by an ImageIO plugin you have installed.

The problem is that the provider class `com.slb.imageio.plugins.wsq.writer.WSQImageWriterSpi` is registered in a resource called `/META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi` (typically inside a JAR). This is incorrect.

It should be in `/META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageWriterSpi`.

As you can see from the stack trace, the exception happens in the `ImageIO` class initialization (`<clinit>`). This is critical and the reason why most/all `ImageIO` methods will fail after this has happened. The Java 6 implementation was probably lenient about it, and registered the provider as an `ImageWriterSpi` regardless (or simply ignored it), while the Java 7 implementation is more strict. The error was always there, it just didn't manifest before now.

**To fix the problem, either contact the vendor and ask for a fix, or update the JAR files and place the correct files in `/META-INF/services/`. If you don't need the plugin that fails, of course you can just remove the JAR containing the plugin from class path.**

Comment: I have removed the JAR file from my project and my JRE. But the problem still exist, any idea?

Comment: Well, then most likely you didn't remove the correct jar. Try searching through the jars you have on classpath for the file mentioned.